# Javascript: prototype method error?

Tags: javascript, function-prototypes, use-strict

I am getting a "TestFunc is not defined" error when this bit of code...

```
/* my_object.js */
"use strict";
function MyObject (param) {
    this.param = param;
}

MyObject.prototype.TestFunc = function () {
    console.log ('in TestFunc');
}

MyObject.prototype.RealFunc = function () {
    // I have tried 3 different ways to call TestFunc:
    // 1.
    this.TestFunc ();

    // 2.
    TestFunc ();

    // 3. (I didn't really think this would work,
    //     but thought it was worth a try...)
    MyObject.TestFunc ();
}
```

...gets run from this bit of code:

```
/* index.js */
var myObj = new MyObject ('test');
myObj.RealFunc (); // Firebug: "TestFunc is not defined"
```

Comment: I tried in firebug with only `this.TestFunc()` and other two commented out, it works fine. Try one more time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// 1.
this.TestFunc ();
```

That's fine. That'll work, with the other calls removed.

(Well, it works as long as you don't peel off the `RealFunc` from its owner and call it on its own, like `var method= myObj.RealFunc; method();` or via an event handler or timeout. In that case `this` in RealFunc wouldn't be the MyObject instance and you'd need to look at closures or `Function.bind` to get it to work.)

```
// 2.
TestFunc ();
```

Nope, TestFunc is not defined as a variable in local or global scope. This causes the error you get from Firebug.

```
// 3. (I didn't really think this would work,
//     but thought it was worth a try...)
MyObject.TestFunc ();
```

No, you were right. :-) It would be `MyObject.prototype.TestFunc.call(this)`, done explicitly.

JavaScript does kind of confuse the matter by putting some of the same methods on the standard constructor functions for built-in objects as on their prototypes (for example `String.split` exists where really only `String.prototype.split` should). But that doesn't happen to your own objects unless you explicitly say something like `MyObject.TextFunc= MyObject.prototype.TextFunc`.

Comment: ah ha!  i didn't include it in the above simplified version, since i totally forgot about what happens to 'this' in an eventhandler, but RealFunc () is indeed an event handler...

Comment: Yeah, I suspected as much... the way method-binding and `this` works in JavaScript is very strange compared to other programming languages; it's probably the most common gotcha.

Answer (score 1):

Variant 1 seems correct. I tried your code in ExecuteJS and skipped 2. and 3., it worked (although I removed the call to `console.log` and changed it to `alert`). `TestFunc` is called within `RealFunc`.

What happens if you remove `"use strict";`?

Comment: ECMAScript Fifth Edition's 'use strict' won't do anything... yet. I look forward to browsers being released where it does, though!